# dotted line span between word and image html problem

Tags: html, css

Below i have hardcoded dotted lines on my menu between the name and image, I cant figure out how to get dotted lines that adjust to the width between where i have them now.

This is the code below that i have. I basically want to remove the hardcoded ..... and make it better somehow with a repeated image inside or just something easier, how can i approach this? I have been boggled with this problem for some time now...

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

  $('.serviceDesc').hide();
  $('.serviceName:first').addClass('active').next().show(); 

  $('.serviceName').click(function(){
  if( $(this).next().is(':hidden') ) { 
  $('.serviceName').removeClass('active').next().slideUp(); 
  $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown(); 
  }
  return false; 
  });

  });
  </script>
  <style>
  #servicesContainer {
      width: 485px;
      height: 400px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      margin-top: 20px;
  }
  h2.serviceName {
      margin: 0;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      margin-top: 5px;
      background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/IcnZl.png);
      background-position: right top;
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
      height: 29px;
      line-height: 24px;
      width: 480px;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: bold;
      float: left;
      color:#000;
  }
  h2.serviceName a {
      color: #000;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
  }
  h2.active {
      background-position: right bottom;
  }
  .serviceDesc {
      margin: 0 0 10px;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 480px;
      clear: both;
  }
  .serviceDesc .block {
  }
  .serviceDesc .block p {
      color: #413f44;
      margin: 0;
      font-size:18px;
  }
  </style>

  <div id="servicesContainer">
    <h2 class="serviceName"><a href="#">Text...............................................................................</a></h2>
    <div class="serviceDesc">
      <div class="block">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h2 class="serviceName"><a href="#">Text...............................................................................</a></h2>
    <div class="serviceDesc">
      <div class="block">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h2 class="serviceName"><a href="#">Text...............................................................................</a></h2>
    <div class="serviceDesc">
      <div class="block">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.<br />
          <br />
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h2 class="serviceName"><a href="#">Text...............................................................................</a></h2>
    <div class="serviceDesc">
      <div class="block">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h2 class="serviceName"><a href="#">Text...............................................................................</a></h2>
    <div class="serviceDesc">
      <div class="block">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h2 class="serviceName"><a href="#">Text...............................................................................<br />
      </a></h2>
    <div class="serviceDesc">
      <div class="block">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h2 class="serviceName"><a href="#">Text...............................................................................</a></h2>
    <div class="serviceDesc">
      <div class="block">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h2 class="serviceName"><a href="#">Text...............................................................................</a></h2>
    <div class="serviceDesc">
      <div class="block">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

You can view an example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/K7MHK/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

creating a  with a repeated by x background image of a dot would be the easiest way.
However you would need to set the element it is in to width:100% or whichever width you want it at.

eg.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .filler{
        background: url(dot.png) bottom left repeat-x;
        float:left;
        width:80%;
      }
      .floating_text {
        float:left;  
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2 class="serviceName"><a href="#">
      <span class="floating_text">Text</span>
      <span class="filler">&nbsp;</span>
    </a></h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

The span appears to hook into the `<h2></h2>` height and not the `<a></a>` height, this is what is causing the problem with it appearing on two lines.

The reason the dots appear to be in the middle of the span in your example is because of your image, remove the white at the bottom and it will appear as normal.

Comment: I remember trying this and it didnt work, let me see if i can try this version.

Comment: interesting, span does not seem to work when empty, I have updated the answer with working code.

Comment: Ad thats better but now it goes under the text and image :(

http://jsfiddle.net/Vdyyy/3/

Maybe there is a way to padd it or something from going through there is that possible?

Comment: But some of the text is different length basically its going under the text now and that just doesnt seem to work ehh..

http://jsfiddle.net/Vdyyy/3/

Comment: updated to work with span, apologies for the delay I forgot div overwrites elements it is in.

Comment: Yeah i see what you did but i was having the same damn problem for some reason now its just under the text. I tried so many variations but it seems like if you put a div in there it acts funky. Heres what we tried just now. http://jsfiddle.net/Vdyyy/6/

Comment: It's doing this because its hooking into the `<h2></h2>` width and not the `<a></a>` width, if you set width to 80% it will appear on the same line but backwards. BUT if you float the text left too it will work, updating answer.

Comment: Dunno seems the same to me?

http://jsfiddle.net/Vdyyy/8/

And i cant make the background white that would be fine but im using a image behind that code.

Maybe i implemented it wrong?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3917/discussion-between-serdalis-and-mystycs)

Comment: Wow i really appreciate all the help you gave me here today.

Answer (score 1):

I feel as though there is a better way to do this, but it is escaping me. Hopefully this helps someone on to a robust answer though. I only did it for the first list item.

http://jsfiddle.net/K7MHK/1/

I use the css border-bottom property to create the dotted line on an element. The question then was - how do you get two elements side-by-side. One to contain the text and the other to contain the dots. The caveat being the dots need to take up the rest of the space. I couldn't figure out a good way.

So instead I made the dots go all the way across, but put the text in a absolutely positioned div. This allows it to float over and hide the dots.

```
/* set h2 to relative so that we can absolutely position an element inside of it */
/* Give it padding so that dots don't intersect the image*/
h2.serviceName {
   padding-right: 50px;
   position: relative;

/* absolutely position div to cover dots and give it bg that matches */
div#a { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; background: white; }
/* modify the height property here to adjust the location of the dots*/
div#b { 
  width: 100%; 
  border-bottom: 1px dotted red; 
  height: 18px; 
}
```

So things that could make this better:

1. Don't rely on absolutely positioned div
2. Perhaps use line-height? to position text so that you don't have to manually adjust dots location.

Comment: That works but the picture seems so spaced and so wide apart.

Comment: Oh i see the background you made white, the problem is i have a background thats an image and this really wouldnt work.. Thats my second problem haha

Comment: This is closer. Turns out #1 above isn't really doable with CSS. http://jsfiddle.net/K7MHK/5/

Answer (score 1):

Okay - another answer after I learned asker can't have elements actually on top of each other. This is because he has a background that needs to show through. After quite a bit of research on SO I found that two dynamically side-by-side divs cannot be made to fill a fixed width. So instead you need to rely on a table.

http://jsfiddle.net/K7MHK/6/

```
   //html
   <h2 class="serviceName"><a href="#">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Text of Variable Length</td>
                <td><div></div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>  
    </a>
   </h2>
```

So instead we use a table which is good at this. The right hand cell autoexpands. Inside we place a div that takes the dotted css border property. We then adjust the position of the dots through the divs height.

```
table { width: 440px; }
table td { white-space: nowrap; }
table td:last-child { width: 100%; }
table td:last-child div { width: 100%; border-bottom: 2px dotted black; height: 15px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would set the css of the a-tag to

```
h2.serviceName a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: 45px;
}
```